# running aws cli on amazon linux returns No module named 'cryptography'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

running `aws` on an aws linux ec2 returns No module named 'cryptography'

updating or installing older version with pip does not help

Comment: What does `pip show cryptography` return?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `pip` to install the AWS CLI tool. That method of installing the CLI tool is deprecated. Follow the installation instructions for the AWS CLI  [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html).